# Spring load command line arguments from xml application context

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext

How can I use varargs from Spring application context xml?

`java -jar my.jar --variable=value`

**application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="fooClassInstance" class="my.package.FooClass">
    <property name="myproperty" value="${variable}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You have written your own `main()` method and create the App Context there? So you have access to the `String[] args` parameter of `main()`? Your question is actually "how can I pass arbitrary string values into the app context"?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use System properties:

```
java -Dvariable=value -jar my.jar
```

That either works out of the box or you need to tell the app context to look at system properties when it expands variables. It's been a while since I tried that.

A good starting point is `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: but if I want to use variables passed by arguments?

Comment: You have written your own `main()` method and create the App Context there? So you have access to the `String[] args` parameter of `main()`?

Answer (score 1):

When you do something like this in your Spring XML config

```
<bean id="fooClassInstance" class="my.package.FooClass">
    <property name="myproperty" value="${variable}" />
</bean>
```

Spring uses `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to search for those variables in System/enviroment variables and/or list of predefined properties files.

So the easiest way is to pass that value as a system or environment variable with `-Dvariable=value`.

If you want to pass those values as arguments into `min` you can still do hacks like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // parse arguments into key, value pairs
    System.setProperty(<key>, <value>);
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(<your XML config file>);
    // use Spring context to get beans
}
```